# Probability of Full House in 5 Cards Given a Pair of Aces

Tags: probability, statistics, poker

What is the probability of a full house in a 5 card hand, given the first 2 cards are aces?

My thought process is that there are 4 other events that could occur:

A: Ace

p: any card of given face

App —> (2/50) * (4/49) * (3/48)

pAp —> (4/50) * (2/49) * (3/48)

ppA —> (4/50) * (3/49) * (2/48)

ppp —> (4/50) * (3/49) * (2/48)

Am I approaching this incorrectly? I believe these are all the possible combinations for which this could occur.

Comment: This is correct.  Do note however the distinction between the problem "Probability of a full house in 5 cards given at least two aces *in any position* in the hand" versus "Probability of a full house in 5 cards given two aces *very specifically in the first two positions* among possibly additional"

Comment: @JMoravitz Isn't this a conditional probability problem?  Also, the rank of the non-ace cards has not been selected.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig in the same way that "Find the probability that the second ball drawn is red given the first ball is red given a bag with 10 balls, 4 of which red" can be done immediately as $\frac{3}{9}$ rather than $\dfrac{\frac{4\cdot 3}{10\cdot 9}}{\frac{4}{10}}$, the above problem can be jumped straight to imagining a 50 card deck and drawing three cards.  That is to say, rather than using $\Pr(A\mid B) = \frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$ you can use the intuitive interpretation of $\Pr(A\mid B)$ as the probability of $A$ when restricted to the smaller sample space where $B$ occurred.

Comment: @JMoravitz I see what you are saying about the conditional probability aspect of the problem, but there are $48$ choices for the first non-ace.

Comment: Good catch.  Yes then, multiply the result above by $12$ representing the selection of what rank `p` represents.  It may be that the OP was still aware of this step and just neglected to mention it, putting the final probability as $12\cdot 4\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2 / (50\cdot 49\cdot 48)$

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**  If the first two cards selected from the deck are aces, then of the remaining $50$ cards, two are aces.  There are $$\binom{50}{3}$$ ways to select three cards from the $50$ that remain.  To obtain a full house, either one of the two remaining aces and two cards from one of the remaining $12$ ranks must be selected or three cards from one of the remaining $12$ ranks must be selected.  Thus, the number of favorable cases is
$$\binom{2}{1}\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{2} + \binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{3}$$
where the first term counts the number of ways of selecting one of the two remaining aces, one of the remaining $12$ ranks, and two cards of that rank and the second term counts the number of ways of selecting one of the remaining $12$ ranks and three of the four cards of that rank.  Hence, the probability of obtaining a full house given the first two cards selected are aces is
$$\frac{\dbinom{2}{1}\dbinom{12}{1}\dbinom{4}{2} + \dbinom{12}{1}\dbinom{4}{3}}{\dbinom{50}{3}}$$

**Method 2:**  We correct your attempt.

You did not take into account the rank of the non-aces.  Observe that there are $48$ cards which can be selected as the first non-ace.  Choosing that card determines the rank of the cards which are non-aces.  Hence, there are three choices for the second non-ace and, if there is a third non-ace, there are two choices for that card.  The probability of selecting an ace, then two cards of one of the other $12$ ranks *in that order* is
$$\frac{2}{50} \cdot \frac{48}{49} \cdot \frac{3}{48}$$
Since there are three possible positions for the remaining ace, the probability of obtaining a full house with three aces given that the first two cards are aces is
$$\frac{2}{50} \cdot \frac{48}{49} \cdot \frac{3}{48} + \frac{48}{50} \cdot \frac{2}{49} \cdot \frac{3}{48} + \frac{48}{50} \cdot \frac{2}{49} \cdot \frac{3}{48} = 3 \cdot \frac{2}{50} \cdot \frac{48}{49} \cdot \frac{3}{48}$$
The probability of obtaining a full house containing three cards of another rank given that the first two cards are aces is
$$\frac{48}{50} \cdot \frac{3}{49} \cdot \frac{2}{48}$$
Hence, the probability of a full house given that the first two cards selected are aces is
$$3 \cdot \frac{2}{50} \cdot \frac{48}{49} \cdot \frac{3}{48} + \frac{48}{50} \cdot \frac{3}{49} \cdot \frac{2}{48}$$

Comment: I see my issue! I was limiting the first non-Ace to a very specific card as opposed to allowing that card to be any non-Ace!  Thank you @N.F. Taussig and others that replied!